# Google BigQuery Sum return wrong result

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

Guys im running this query on public blockchain data, to get total burned tokens. But SUM return result much less then real(run same query without sum and run sum in Pandas). it gives 8306 while pandas 328608.

log.data - hex number

```
SELECT
  SUM(SAFE_CAST(log.data as INT64)/POW(10,18))
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.logs` AS log
WHERE TRUE
  AND log.address = '0xf53ad2c6851052a81b42133467480961b2321c09'
  AND log.block_timestamp >= '2018-01-01 00:00:01'
  AND log.block_timestamp <= '2018-12-01 00:00:01'
  AND SUBSTR(log.topics[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], 1, 10) IN ('0x42696c68','0xcc16f5db')
```

im not quite understand why this happens. Will be appreciate for answer)

Comment: Could it be that Google might try to localise the timestamp column (`log.block_timestamp`) and it will result in another set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that some of the `log.data` values are excluded from the `SUM`, since they don't fit in the range of `INT64` and hence the `SAFE_CAST(log.data AS INT64)` returns `NULL`. As an example, `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080b7978da47c78d2` is greater than the max `INT64` value of `9223372036854775807`, which is `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal.

You can instead cast the `log.data` values to the `FLOAT64` type, which produces a result closer to what you see using Pandas:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CAST(log.data as FLOAT64)/POW(10,18))
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.logs` AS log
WHERE TRUE
  AND log.address = '0xf53ad2c6851052a81b42133467480961b2321c09'
  AND log.block_timestamp >= '2018-01-01 00:00:01'
  AND log.block_timestamp <= '2018-12-01 00:00:01'
  AND SUBSTR(log.topics[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], 1, 10) IN ('0x42696c68','0xcc16f5db')
```

This returns `329681.7942642243`.